# Text Editor Document Model

Tags: modeling

I am working on a text editor in javascript. I have created the front end and i need to prototype a backend. I need to model the structure of the document using this as hierarchy:

Character
 , Word
 , Tag
 , Document

I am trying to create objects based on this hierarchy.

For example:

Characters are represented a linked list. Word are pointers to the first and last characters. Tags are another linked list of words, and a document is a collection of words and tags.

I am was wondering if anyone has a better suggestion to model these relationships as classes. I receive a character from the keyboard and i need to store this as an object in my document model.

thanks

Comment: Could you reword this to identify the problem that you are having editing characters?  It would help it fit into the SE format better than asking for various suggestions (which may be equally correct, but not actually fix your problem).

Comment: A linked list of characters, for a text editor?!? That easily makes the document take **five** times as much space as necessary! **Nine** times on 64 bit machines. Not to mention that many operations will become severely less efficient due to your code going crazy hopping all over memory. Why do you think you need a linked list?

Comment: i need to apply styles to characters such as bold and italic. So i thought using individual character objects would be easier to implement than storing words.

Comment: I don't understand the diference between your char and word objects. If you need particular formatting for a char, why not specify it on the word object? The char object should be a char, not a linked list. Will you have a linked list of blanks between each word?

Comment: A character has some additional properties such as raw, and formatted values. So i was thining to model it as a separate object. I was thinking of some kind of separator symbol, between character objects to signify a word, but there would also be a word object that has pointer to the first and last chacter objects, as opposed to pointing to all character objects.

Comment: I do agree that modelling a character object, will take up memory. Should I not use this granular of a level?

Comment: I would point out that the fair chunk of the [Design Patterns](http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612/) is dealing with a word processor and the patterns to make it fit together.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to take a look at [Data Structures for Text Sequences](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~crowley/papers/sds/sds.html), by Charles Crowley.

These 5 notes: [1](ftp://ftp.uu.net/pub/text-processing/vi/docs/editech.1.Z), [2](ftp://ftp.uu.net/pub/text-processing/vi/docs/editech.2.Z), [3](ftp://ftp.uu.net/pub/text-processing/vi/docs/editech.3.Z), [4](ftp://ftp.uu.net/pub/text-processing/vi/docs/editech.4.Z), [5](ftp://ftp.uu.net/pub/text-processing/vi/docs/editech.5.Z), have a lot of information on Old School text editor data structures.  They may interest you for a number of reasons. First, performance was limited when those were written, so they may end up as very high speed structures today.  Second, programs were a lot harder to write, so the very simplicity may appeal to you if you're just trying to get a working back end.